# How to extract the Video Muxer part from StagefrightRecorder?

Tags: android, media, android-source, stagefright, mediamuxer

I am trying to build an video recording system on `Android 4.2.2`, I've done the encoding part, which is using `OMX`. Now I am working on the Muxer part, since the code stream of the video can be a little different if I use `FFMpeg`, so I wish to use the exact same Muxer tool of the original system.
So I want to extract the Muxer part of `StagefrightRecorder`, compile it into a .so file, and then call it via `JNI` in my application. But there are a lot of stuffs in `StagefrightRecorder`, I am confused.

Can this way work? Can I just extract the code relevant to MPEG4Writer? Can anyone give me any instructions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are compiling within the context of the framework, you could simply include the relevant header files and create the `MPEG4Writer` object directly. A very good example for this is the command line utility `recordVideo` as can be observed from [this file](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/recordvideo.cpp#298).

If you wish to write a separate application, then you need to link with `libstagefright.so` and include the relevant header files and their path.

**Note:** If you wish to work with the standard `MPEG4Writer`, it's source i.e. source of the `MPEG4Writer` which would be an encoder should be modeled as a `MediaSource`. The writer pulls the `metadata` and actual bitstream through the `read` method and hence, it is recommended to employ a standard built-in object such as `OMXCodec` or `ACodec` for the encoder.

Comment: Thank you! I want this to be a separate application. If I want to use the first method, I have to compile the whole system on the device, have I? I have another question: when we call .so file via NDK, we need to have a corresponding .h file. Is there a .h file for libstagefright.so?

Comment: @BrendonTsai.. `libstagefright.so` includes many modules with inter-dependent header files. It is recommended to include files from http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/ and http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/include/ which should satisfy all your dependencies